# Samsung Galaxy Core Prime non responsive touch screen and back button for a while

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

I am using Samsung Galaxy Core Prime. Everything has been running smooth except the fact that for sometime I'm facing a strange problem of touch screen as well as touch button (Back button) at the same time. For example, when I chat using either Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp, sometimes I observe while typing in the keys the screen behaves abnormally i.e. if I try to erase a character there appears a new line or so. The keys don't respond.

At the moment, if I touch the Back button instead of going back to the previous app a new app appears (say Google+ here). Moreover, if I try to swipe down to go to the settings at the same time it pops down partially and disappears. The touch screen doesn't work entirely for a while. The problem vanishes automatically after a while, but very annoying as it occurs repeatedly.

I have 360 Security Antivirus installed and scanning shows no viruses either. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: he is a nonsense guy who actually downvoted this question instead of solving my problem..because there is no nonsense thing in my question!

Comment: Hi Rosemary! I don't see nonsense in the question except the fact that there were some glaring typos (which you should've removed by reading the question before posting it) which I corrected now. Plus, there is no point in mocking the person who downvoted your question, other than to kindly ask the reason for downvote. // Anyhow, I'm not that downvoter of course, if it matters. :)

Comment: Just wondering, Are you using a screen protector and more specifically, is it a tempered glass one? My mom always used Invisishield(the plastic ones) on her phones and here recently, she tried one of the tempered glass ones on her Note 4 and it was causing all kinds of mis-presses and etc. Removed it and the phone was good as new.

Comment: thank you @jer3my for the response. Yeah,I have also a screen protector but not sure whether it is tempered glass, but it seems like plastic.

Comment: Try taking that off for a few days. There were cases those "boxes" caused strange behavior.

Comment: This could be a hardware problem, not a software problem.